# How to run node.js script on ftp server?

Tags: node.js, server

I've developed a wallpaper app whose backend is written in `node.js` . Everything in development was fine then today I bought a `vps server` with `cpanel` for 3 months from a hosting service provider .But I'm a complete beginner in `server management` so now how to run this `node.js` script in my ftp server . Can anyone please guide me to run node.js script on server ?

It may sound like off-topic but please do help me to fix my problem.

I'm a complete beginner so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.

Comment: An FTP server can't run nodejs. https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: @lkroneman thanks for your answer sir but how to get ssh access to vps could you please elaborate or suggest any tutorial for that

Comment: Questions on _professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. This might be migrated to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: No question that's honest and *explains how you found your way to the problem* is foolish :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no support for using Node.js with cPanel. But I can recommend you to use for example [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for testing or hobby development. Heroku is free, very simple and cool for small projects.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a simple, single node.js script, I'd recommend running this as a lambda function – basically, use a service that will run this script at a given HTTP endpoint without needing to manage a server. This can be free depending on how much it's used. For example, here are some places to run it:

- https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-workers-unleashed/
- https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/
- https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

As CenyGG suggested, Heroku is also a great place to do this and will be free if you don't need the app to be live 24/7 (it will go to sleep and take a few seconds to "wake up" if it hasn't been used in a while).